# Integral cohomology of compact Lie groups and their classifying spaces

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, lie-groups, cohomology

Let $G$ be a compact Lie group and let $BG$ be its classifying space. Let $\gamma\colon \Sigma G \to BG$ be the adjoint map for a natural weak equivalence $G \xrightarrow{\sim} \Omega BG$. Taking rational cohomology, it is well-known, that the map $\gamma$ induces an isomorphism between indecomposable elements $QH^*(BG,\mathbb{Q})$ and primitive elements $\mathrm{Prim}\, H^{*-1}(G,\mathbb{Q})$. But I want to know what happens integrally.

To be more precise, the integral cohomology ring modulo torsion $H^*(G,\mathbb{Z})/\mathrm{Tor}$ is still a Hopf algebra isomorphic to an exterior algebra (see Mimura, Toda - Topology of Lie groups, I and II, Chapter VII, Theorem  1.22). Is the homomorphism induced by $\gamma$ still surjective onto primitive elements? If not, what one can say about orders of cokernels?